# Problem with private router in react app in React Router v6

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

Everything is working for the lower version but not working in the v6 version. I have gone through many articles related to the private route for v6 but not succeed.

In app.js file

```
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/account" component={Profile} />
```

In ProtectedRoute.js file

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ isAdmin, component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { loading, isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading === false && (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={(props) => {
            if (isAuthenticated === false) {
              return <Redirect to="/login" />;
            }

            if (isAdmin === true && user.role !== "admin") {
              return <Redirect to="/login" />;
            }

            return <Component {...props} />;
          }}
        />
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

They actually made it a lot easier.

if you look at the [example on their doc](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth) you will see how they did it

Try something like this :

```
// ProtectedRoute
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute: FC = ({auth, children }) => {
  if (!auth) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: not working yet.